# MySQL workbench reads only last line

Tags: mysql

I am learning to use MySql workbench, everytime i use scripts it only reads the latest statement, for example in a code like this

```
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact, cust_email)
VALUES('1000000001', 'Village Toys', '200 Maple Lane', 'Detroit', 'MI', '44444', 'USA', 'John Smith', 'sales@villagetoys.com');
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact)
VALUES('1000000002', 'Kids Place', '333 South Lake Drive', 'Columbus', 'OH', '43333', 'USA', 'Michelle Green');
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact, cust_email)
VALUES('1000000003', 'Fun4All', '1 Sunny Place', 'Muncie', 'IN', '42222', 'USA', 'Jim Jones', 'jjones@fun4all.com');
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact, cust_email)
VALUES('1000000004', 'Fun4All', '829 Riverside Drive', 'Phoenix', 'AZ', '88888', 'USA', 'Denise L. Stephens', 'dstephens@fun4all.com');
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact)
VALUES('1000000005', 'The Toy Store', '4545 53rd Street', 'Chicago', 'IL', '54545', 'USA', 'Kim Howard');
```

I only have the last creation

```
INSERT INTO Customers(cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact)
VALUES('1000000005', 'The Toy Store', '4545 53rd Street', 'Chicago', 'IL', '54545', 'USA', 'Kim Howard');
```

The others do not work and i have to put them in line by line

Comment: try this please.[ use `Ctrl + A` to select all and then execute.]

Comment: did u try union command between insert commands

Comment: By the way, `UNION` is for `SELECT statement`

Comment: I tried now and your query works ,added all data to database

Answer (score 2):

I was using the shortcut <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute code, that only works for the last line, to properly execute all the code it's written the correct shortcut is <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Crtl+Shift+Enter` executes only the selection if any.

Answer (score 0):

While you already gave the correct answer, I just wanted to suggest that you can also make multiple inserts in one statement which also improves performance.

```
INSERT INTO Customers(
     cust_id, cust_name, cust_address, cust_city,
     cust_state, cust_zip, cust_country, cust_contact, cust_email
) VALUES (
     '1000000003', 'Fun4All', '1 Sunny Place', 'Muncie', 'IN', '42222', 'USA',
     'Jim Jones', 'jjones@fun4all.com'
), (
     '1000000004', 'Fun4All', '829 Riverside Drive', 'Phoenix', 'AZ', '88888', 'USA', 
     'Denise L. Stephens', 'dstephens@fun4all.com'
);
```

Please be aware that you might hit the max_query_size limit if your insert query is greater than `max_allowed_packet --> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`